# How to generate a list of random values with summation =1

Tags: python

How to generate a list of  random  values  similar to  below:

```
 X     Y
0.2  0.8
0.1  0.9
0.6  0.4
0.3  0.7
```

**The summation of x  and y should be = 1**

Comment: Generate random `x` between 0 and 1 and guess what `y` should be.

Answer (score 2):

## Pandas

Try using the pandas data-frame `sum` function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
l = random.sample(list(np.arange(0.0,1.0,0.1)),4)
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': l,
                   'Y': ''})
df['Y'] = 1-df['X']
print(df.sum(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

## Regular python

Just simply do the below code:

```
l = random.sample(list(np.arange(0.0,1.0,0.1)),4)
s = '\n'.join([str(x)+' '+str(y) for x,y in list(zip(l,[str(1-i) for i in l]))])
for i in s.splitlines():
    print(sum([float(i) for i in i.split()]))
```

Output:

```
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```